# Give root password for maintenance

Tags: linux, debian

After entering

```
shutdown now
```

in terminal I get everything running normally and then:

```
All processes ended withing 2 seconds...done
INIT: Going single user
INIT: Sending processes the TERM signal
INIT: Sending processes the KILL signal
Give root password for maintenance(or....
```

I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, and it shows me login screen Debian. Shutdown through GUI works properly.

**UPDATE 1**

It seems some process hangs.

Moreover, I've managed to power off the server through several retries. Recently I've installed only ntp and ntpdate, nothing more.

I suppose it might be it conflicting with iptables.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use the `-h` switch to halt the system. Default for `shutdown` is to switch to run level 1 (maintenance).

```
shutdown -h now
```

See `man shutdown`.

Comment: Interesting. Is this new or debian specfic?

Comment: Neither new nor debian specific, it's the same on SuSE (and goes back at least 15 years there). RHEL and descendants do this differently, I believe.

Comment: Not at all -- it's been the default for the last 10 years to my knowledge.  It's not Linux specific -- the Solaris shutdown manpage says "By default, shutdown brings the system to a state where only the console  has access to the operating system. This state is called single-user."

Comment: Haven't tested it on Debian, but on ubuntu to power off the system you could also use the command `poweroff` without any arguments.

Comment: @womble you can easily multiply that 10 by 3, it already has this in 80's BSDs.

Comment: `poweroff` is usually part of whatever gives you `init`, and is certainly present in all modern implementations, including upstart, systemd, busybox, and recent versions of SysVinit.

Comment: @Legolas: Technically I can't, because it's 10 years "to my knowledge".  Just showing my n00bness, I guess.  <grin>

Answer (score 6):

Use the -h option to shutdown to request a halt or a power off instead of just requesting to init that you are going to single user mode (which seems to be the default behaviour)

```
shutdown -h now
```

Answer (score 6):

`shutdown now` drops your Debian to `maintenance mode`. Use `shutdown -h now` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can save some typing by using 'halt' instead of 'shutdown -h now'

Comment: No, not really.  Some versions of `init` have this behavior, but others issue a `halt` instruction in this case, which frequently results in a system hang or reboot.  I just tested this on some vm's I have handy, and on upstart and SysVinit, `halt` is a synonym for `poweroff`, but on systemd, it hangs after stopping init.

Comment: Which init does Debian use by default? The rest are pretty irrelevant to a SE answer I believe, and I've never had halt fail on any debian machine I've tried it on.

Comment: With regards to TokenMacGuy’s comment that `halt` hangs the system, this is true on FreeBSD at least. On FreeBSD, you need `halt -p` to actually power the system off after halting.